# How can I create a spectrum of options in LaTeX?

Tags: graphics

I need to make something like this:
[image]

How would I do it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 6):

This looks a bit like a tree, so `forest` may be an appropriate tool.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=north,l sep+=2em,s sep+=2em}
 [,coordinate
  [W\textsubscript{1},label=above:{Dr.\ Arzt}]
  [W\textsubscript{2},label=above:{Dr.\ Betz}]
  [W\textsubscript{3},label=above:{Dr.\ Curtz}]
  [W\textsubscript{4},label=above:{Dr.\ Dietz}]
  [Etc.]
 ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also use a `tikz` mindmap.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed.